# How to maintain common model classes for JSON with common outer body?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have maintained the below format for all the web service responses :

```
{
    "status": "Status Code",
    "description": "Success/Failure Message",
    "data": {
        "response_object": {},
        "response_array": []
    }
}
```

I am parsing it using GSON using following model classes :

**JSONResponse:**

```
public class JSONResponse {


    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private Data data;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Data:**

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("response_object")
    private ResponseObject responseObject;

    @SerializedName("response_array")
    private List<ORCResponse> orcResponses = new ArrayList<>();

    public ResponseObject getResponseObject() {
        return responseObject;
    }

    public List<ORCResponse> getOrcResponses() {
        return orcResponses;
    }
}
```

Converting JSON to Model object :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONResponse jsonResponse = gson.fromJson(receivedJSON, JSONResponse.class);
```

Now, the problem is the format of JSON under **data** element might change depending upon the web service.

My queries :

1. Is it possible to parse the inner JSON using different model
   depending upon the web service response?
2. Am I using a wrong approach? 
   The reason I am doing this is - I want to parse the data depending on the **status** and to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: _Now, the problem is the format of JSON under data element might change depending upon the web service_

Comment: If your data element changes but you Data class has all the available field needed, you can still use this same response. However, you must send the data field. Even for empty response in cases.

Comment: In class basis, you will just need to check for the required fields from Data class and others will stay null. :)

Comment: @henrik : Lets say I have 2 web services ServiceA and ServiceB with corresponding responses ResponseA and ResponseB with different JSON formats.

Comment: @aa_oo : I am already doing it in a same way as you are suggesting. But now I have a situation where for ServiceA, the response is **array of objects** and for ServiceB, the response is **array of string array**.

Answer (score 0):

If your data element changes but you Data class has all the available field needed, you can still use this same response. However, you must send the data field. Even for empty response in cases.

Use [InstanceOF](http://%09%20If%20your%20data%20element%20changes%20but%20you%20Data%20class%20has%20all%20the%20available%20field%20needed,%20you%20can%20still%20use%20this%20same%20response.%20However,%20you%20must%20send%20the%20data%20field.%20Even%20for%20empty%20response%20in%20cases.) to determine your instance and do accordingly.

```
if(param instanceof Object) {
System.out.println("param is a Object");
}
else if( param instanceof String[]) {
  System.out.println("param is String array");
}
```

Hope it helps, Cheers!